# Flex/Flash Builder: Embedding the same asset in multiple components

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, embed

If I embed the same asset (i.e. image or sound file) in multiple components within a Flex Application, does the compiled swf contain the asset (and it's file size) only once or once for each time it is embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Embedding the same asset multiple time will make your swf higher. It would not take one time the file size of the application will the **No of times x Assest**. For example if you are using the same asset twice, the compiled swf will be twice than the single time embed.

I tried as below

my code as follows

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Embed(source="CD2_AUDIO.mp3")]
        [Bindable]
        public var sndCls:Class;

        [Embed(source="CD2_AUDIO.mp3")]
        [Bindable]
        public var sndCls2:Class;

        public var snd:Sound = new sndCls() as Sound; 
        public var sndChannel:SoundChannel;

        public function playSound():void {
            sndChannel=snd.play();
        }   

        public function stopSound():void {
            sndChannel.stop();
        }   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Button label="play" click="playSound();"/>
    <mx:Button label="stop" click="stopSound();"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

Note: The size of the audio is 26 MB

after build i went to bin-debug and noticed the file size of the application is around 57,004,925  bytes because i had used twice.

when i used the asset only one time it shows 28,817,403  bytes.

hence the application increases the no of times you use.

```
                          ~~~~~Happy Coding~~~~~
```

Comment: 'Merged into code' and 'RSL' define how the Flex framework and/or other external libraries are linked into your application. I fail to see how that is relevant to this question.

Comment: @RIAstar Thanks for specifying here. I did mistake by merging some other content. I modified my answer.